# Emissive material example in Three.js

Tags: three.js

Could somebody provide an example of using the emissive property available in the meshLambertMaterial and meshPhongMaterial. I would say something like a sphere emitting like a sun.

This example looks similar to what I would like to achieve at the end:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=efUpE_nABBM&t=1m52s

However, any introduction would be good for now and I can't find nothing like this around the net.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example where not only all the material properties are explored but changes can be made on different material types: [Material Explorer](http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Color-Explorer.html)